# loading class from latest version of library jar with URLClassloader

Tags: java, classloader

I have 2 versions of jar file (plugins1.0.jar and plugins2.0,jar) in same folder and trying to load Class from these jar files dynamically using URLClassloader.
I want to ensure that the class should be loaded from latest version of jar file.

How can i achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to construct your list of urls in such a way that `plugins2.0.jar` occurs before `plugins1.0.jar`. But generally it's a bad idea as other classes may have conflicting versions loaded.

From [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL%5B%5D%29)

> The URLs will be searched in the order
>   specified for classes and resources
>   after first searching in the parent
>   class loader.

Comment: Yeah,forwhile I'm sorting my list of files using following code Arrays.sort(fileArray, new Comparator<Object>() { compare method for lastmodified date } , but not sure if it is good approach.